# Flutter web overflows vertically on android mobile chrome browser

Tags: android, flutter, dart, canvas

Code works fine on large screens but on mobile Chrome browser container with screen height and width overflow vertically, **until I touch screen once**.

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: Get.height,
        width: Get.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey,
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 18
          )
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Screen at first, without touch on screen

[image]

When I touch once on screen

[image]